# Regex validation rule to avoid special characters not applying for the text field in laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation, laravel-6

In my laravel application I have a form to register new domain. In that form I'm trying to validate a text field (subDomainName) to avoid special characters. But all the other rues are working properly except the regex for that input field.

Code for My form as follows,

```
<form id="w1" action="{{ route('app.save') }}" method="post">
                        @csrf

                            <input type="text" id="app-subdomainname" class="form-control @error('subDomainName') is-invalid @enderror" name="subDomainName" placeholder="{{ __('sentence.Sub Domain Name') }}" value="{{ old('subDomainName') }}"  aria-required="true">

                            @error('subDomainName')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                         <br>
                            <select id="app-subdomainsuffix" class="form-control @error('subDomainSuffix') is-invalid @enderror" name="subDomainSuffix" aria-required="true">
                                <option value="">- {{ __('sentence.Select domains') }} -</option>
                                <option value="TEST.SITE">TEST.SITE</option>
                            </select>

                            @error('subDomainSuffix')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                        <br>

                        <select id="app-packagetype" class="form-control @error('packageType') is-invalid @enderror" name="packageType" aria-required="true">
                            <option value="">- {{ __('sentence.Select package type') }} -</option>
                            @foreach($packages as $package)
                            <option value="{{$package->id}}">{{$package->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                        </select>
                        @error('packageType')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                        <br>
                            <select id="app-payment" class="form-control @error('paymentoption') is-invalid @enderror" name="paymentoption" aria-required="true">
                            <option value="">- {{ __('sentence.Select Payment Option') }} -</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('paymentoption')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                        <br>

                            <select id="app-themeid" class="form-control @error('themeid') is-invalid @enderror" name="themeid" aria-required="true">
                                <option value="">- {{ __('sentence.Select theme') }} -</option>
                                <option value="default">default</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('themeid')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                        <br>
                            <select id="app-lang" class="form-control @error('lang') is-invalid @enderror" name="lang" aria-required="true">
                                <option value="">- {{ __('sentence.Select Language') }} -</option>
                                <option value="en">English</option>
                                <option value="fr">French</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('lang')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                        <br>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" id="domain" class="form-control" name="domain" >
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default subscribe px-5">{{ __('sentence.Save') }}</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

And my controller's validation as follows,

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'subDomainName' => 'required','regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$)+/',
            'subDomainSuffix' => 'required',
            'lang' => 'required',
            'themeid' => 'required',
            'paymentoption' => 'required',
            'packageType' =>'required',
            'domain' => 'unique:apps',

        ]);
```

And all the validations are working properly except the regex....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want multiple validation rule on a single field you should either put it in one string separated with a pipe `|` or put it into an array. try this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'subDomainName' => [
                'required',
                'regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/'
            ],
            'subDomainSuffix' => 'required',
            'lang' => 'required',
            'themeid' => 'required',
            'paymentoption' => 'required',
            'packageType' =>'required',
            'domain' => 'unique:apps',

        ]);
```

I've also shortened your regex string a little.

Comment: as of laravel 7, docs recommend using regular expression rules in form of array like you did in your answer instead of pipe